# Xaml according to Nested collection structure

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have the Property

```
ObservableCollection<List<AuditViewModel>>Audits
```

and i want to represent it in a xaml as a grid where the observableCollection represent the rows and the List represent the columns.

any idea how can i do it?

Thanks, Lin.

Comment: What would the cell represent?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ListBox control and bind it's ItemSource to Audits. That gets you the rows. Then you could create an itemtemplate for the listview that displays all the values of the AuditViewModel. That ItemTemplate will be bound to AuditViewModel. Should just be "{Binding}".